# Flutter: How can I assign results from a BlocBuilder to a IconData?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have this piece of Dart code used in a Flutter app. It's using the flutter_bloc library.

```dart
icon: BlocBuilder<SongsBloc, SongsState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
       var songSelected = context
         .watch<SongsBloc>()
         .state
         .getSongById(widget.song.id!)
         .selected!;
       return songSelected
           ? FontAwesomeIcons.circleCheck
           : FontAwesomeIcons.circle;
   },
)
```

Here, `icon` is `IconData?`. The idea is to update the icon on song selection change. But I get the following error message.

```
The argument of type 'BlocBuilder<SongsBloc, SongsState>' cannot be assigned to the parameter of type 'IconData?'
```

From the code above `BlocBuilder` returns `IconData`, therefore the error is not expected.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting data inside method.

```
final currentState = BlocProvider.of<SongsBloc>(context).state
 //if you have multiple state check here with `state is StateA`
bool songSelected = currentState.getSongById(widget.song.id!).selected??false;
final icon =  songSelected ? FontAwesomeIcons.circleCheck : FontAwesomeIcons.circle;

// now iuse this `icon` on params.
```

For widget case,You can use `BlocBuilder` on top of this widget.

```
BlocBuilder<SongsBloc, SongsState>(
     builder: (context, state) {
       var songSelected =  state.getSongById(widget.song.id!).selected??false;
       return Icon( songSelected
             ? FontAwesomeIcons.circleCheck
             : FontAwesomeIcons.circle);
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear. `icon` is a named parameter, what exactly do you mean by on top of the widget?

Comment: Are you trying to pass iconData to a different widget? and does `getSongById` defined on `SongsState`?  It would be easier if you include more context

Comment: `getSongById` is defined on `SongsState`. I'm passing `IconData` to named parameter `icon` of type `IconData?`, to which `BlocBuilder` should provide the return `IconData`.

Comment: try using top part by reading from context , you can make it on single line if needed